# Assign and return a variable inside .subscribe()

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to assign a variable inside a `.subscribe` but I can't get it to return the right value. Code is posted below, let me know how I can get the variable success to be returned correctly.

```
createIndexes(environmentName, csvReindexCommands){
    let success = false;
    this.swaggerApi.createOrUpdateElasticSearchIndexSchema(environmentName, csvReindexCommands).subscribe(
        x => {success = x.success}, 
        err => {success = err.statusText}
    ); 

    return success 
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
successCounter = 0;
errorCounter = 0;
createIndexes(environments, csvReindexCommands){
   for (let i = 0; i < environments.length; i++){
    this.swaggerApi.createOrUpdateElasticSearchIndexSchema(environments[i], csvReindexCommands).subscribe(
        x => {this.successCounter += 1}, 
        err => {this.errorCounter += 1}
    ); 
   }
   displayNotification("This operation ran successfully " + this.successCounter + " times. ")
}
```

Comment: Check out MDN in my answer about arrow functions. You're currently using passing "x" as a parameter into the function but not using it. You'll need to pass "success" instead

Comment: You cannot return a value that way. You should return the observable itself and subscribe to it where you want to get the result.

Comment: But when I subscribe to it where i need it, I still need to try and assign it to a variable outside the .subscribe scope ... so regardless i need to assign it to a variable. Any other ideas?

Comment: You should assign the variable inside the subscribe callback. Why can't you do that?

Comment: What do you mean by callback? I'm currently assigning the variable inside the subscribe but it doesn't immediately update. A code sample would really help!

Comment: You have to do something like `myObservable(...).subscribe(x => { this.success = x.success })`. The value of `this.success` is then available in your code. If that is still not clear, please show us what you want to do with `createIndexes`.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. However, after assigning the variable, I'm not able to immediately use it afterwards because the operation still seems to be running. Only when I `setTimeout` for a few milliseconds is `this.success` available to be used. Any way to more systematically wait for the operation to be over, and then use the variable?

Comment: Instead of doing `setTimeout(() => { doSomething(); }, 100)`, use the same callback function like this: `myObservable(...).subscribe(x => { this.success = x.success; doSomething(); })`. Or `myObservable(...).subscribe(x => { doSomething(x.success); })`.

Comment: Yeah that works, but I have a loop that repeatedly calls .subscribe, each time causing a counter variable to increase by 1. When the loop ends, then I want to display the counter variable. So the function must be called outside .subscribe ... is setTimeout the only solution?

Comment: `setTimeout` is not the way to do it. The counter should be incremented inside the subscribe callbacks. The counter value can then be displayed using data binding in the template.

Comment: You can also merge several observables into a single observable and subscribe only once.

Comment: I've just updated my question with the code I currently have. I'm incrementing the counter inside the subscribe callbacks, but the console.logs still do not output the updated values, unless I have a setTimeout before outputting the new data. Also, thanks for all the help thus far!

Comment: Try `x => { this.successCounter += 1; console.log(this.successCounter); }`. All the processing must be done inside the subscribe callback. If you use `{{successCounter}}` in the template, you will see the correct value.

Comment: Yep I get that, but I don't want to display it in the template, I wish to display it in a notification (see above for updated code). But the notification returns '0' because the values aren't updated ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173249/discussion-between-j-tey-and-connorsfan).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are working with **[`async programming`](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/introduction-to-asynchronous-javascript)**  you cannot pause the execution of the code or make it wait and your subscription will be resolved in future but you cannot predict when.  `displayNotification` outside the `subscribe` is executed before your subscription is resolved that's why it's undefined
.

If you need to make Multiple HTTP Request you should go for `RXJS` operators which makes your job easier.
You can use
[`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)
[`concatMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)
[`forkJoin`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

your question is the perfect use case for `concatMap`
[`Requests with concatMap() vs mergeMap() vs forkJoin()`](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293)

**Update your service**

```
createOrUpdateElasticSearchIndexSchema(environments:any[].......)
{
   return from(environments)
  .pipe(
     concatMap(id => <Observable<any>> this.httpc.post('url;))
  );
}
```

There are three functions available to send data to the subscribers of the observable
`complete(): void` The Observer callback to receive a valueless notification of type complete from the Observable.

`error(err: any): void` The Observer callback to receive notifications of type error from the Observable, with an attached Error.

`next(value: T): void` The Observer callback to receive notifications of type next from the Observable, with a value.
During observable execution, there can be infinite calls to the `observer.next()`, however, when `observer.error()` or `observer.complete()` is called, the execution stops and no more data will be delivered to the subscribers.

You can use `complete` for your use case..

**Component:**

```
successCounter = 0;
errorCounter = 0;
createIndexes(environments, csvReindexCommands){

    this.swaggerApi.createOrUpdateElasticSearchIndexSchema(environments[i], csvReindexCommands).subscribe(
        x => this.successCounter += 1, 
        err => this.errorCounter += 1,
        ()=>displayNotification("This operation ran successfully " + this.successCounter + " times. ")
    ); 
   }
```

You could also leverage the [`finalize`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/finalize.html) operator for it.

```
createIndexes(environments, csvReindexCommands){
this.swaggerApi.createOrUpdateElasticSearchIndexSchema(environments[i], csvReindexCommands).
pipe(finalize(()=>displayNotification("This operation ran successfully " + this.successCounter + " times. "))
.subscribe(
           x => this.successCounter += 1, 
           err => this.errorCounter += 1,

        ); 
       }
```

**[`LIVE DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v4sdum)**